# Is there a way to select sum on one column based on other DISTINCT column, while grouping by third column(date) only

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three columns

```
year  |  money  | id
2020     100      01
2020     100      01
2019     50       02    
2018     50       03
2020     40       04
```

results should be

```
Year    |   Money   | total people
2020    |    240    |   4
```

** AS first two ids are the same, I tried it as below

select year, sum(money), Count( Distinct id) from table
group by year

But the result shows 4 people which is the correct but wrong sum, as it is counting all of the money

Comment: If money is different for same id, year then what is expected? Which money should be taken into accout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and then aggregate again:

```
select max(year), sum(money), count(*)
from (select distinct year, money, id
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: awwwesome thanks that worked, I found this answer while solving that issue today. but I really appreciate the way you looked at the problem. It was exactly what the problem was. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`.

For example:

```
select 
  year,
  sum(money) as money,
  (select count(distinct id) from t) as total_people
from t
where year = 2020
group by year;
```

Result:

```
YEAR  MONEY  TOTAL_PEOPLE 
----- ------ ------------ 
2020  240    4
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c359af421e13e45e2f350b028bee03aa).

Answer (score 0):

Not the most performant, but if you wish to avoid a derived table, you can do

```
select distinct 
       max(year) over (), 
       sum(money) over (), 
       count(*) over ()
from t
group by year, money, id;
```

And if you want this grouped by year, you can define the partitions in the `over` clause

Comment: What is the point of selecting analytic max(year) in this query? Why not simply show each year in its own right?

Comment: @mathguy Judging from the desired output (which isn't too intuitive) it seemed to me the OP is asking --*Up until 2020, how much money and how many distinct users do we have?*